# Can you cast Sequester on yourself after creating a Simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, simulacrum

Is possible to cast [Sequester](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sequester) on yourself after having a [Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum)?

I can have my real body protected for years as my Simulacrum lives my life. Something like [The Flesh](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flesh) from *Doctor Who*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, but you'll probably want the *clone* spell instead

There's nothing in the way the spells work that stops this from happening. You create a simulacrum of yourself and then presumably someone else casts *sequester* on you, to which you are willing. This leaves a simulacrum of you free to do as you have commanded it. There are some significant ways in which a simulacrum is not you. It can't regain spell slots and have half your maximum hit points. It's a construct, so many forms of healing won't work. It can't learn or level up for you, and it won't make death saves when it's reduced to 0 HP but rather it will die instantly at that point.

So what can you do instead of using two 7th-level spells and 6500 gp? Well, fortunately for you there is a spell specifically for the thing you describe (or at least almost): [*clone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone). This 8th-level spell will only cost you 3000 gp (2000 of which is reusable) and leaves the full, actual you roaming around with a nice, fresh backup ready should something go... wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was mostly trying to find a canon way to have an immortal wizard. Instead of just having a Clone for when you die, you would have a Simulacrum to be you while you are frozen in time. The simulacrum just watched the history to unfold.